# CMIS workbench: create document with mandatory multi values

Tags: cmis, opencmis, cmis-workbench

We are writing a CMIS server by using OpenCMIS. We have a new document type with some mandatory multi-value properties.
Now I tried to add a new document in workbench by opening "Create Document" dialog. The mandatory properties are listed in this dialog. But I don't know how to enter multi-values. I tried some separators (e.g. *a,b*, *"a","b"*, *["a","b"]*, *[a,b]* and others), but always an error is shown like

> IllegalArgumentException: Property 'xx:propIdXX' is not a single value property!

The log has following entry:

```
18:46:54 ERROR hemistry.opencmis.workbench.ClientHelper: IllegalArgumentException: Property 'xx:propIdXX' is not a single value property!
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'xx:propIdXX' is not a single value property!
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.repository.ObjectFactoryImpl.convertProperties(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:437)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionImpl.createDocument(SessionImpl.java:751)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.workbench.model.ClientModel.createDocument(ClientModel.java:279)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.workbench.CreateDocumentDialog$4.actionPerformed(CreateDocumentDialog.java:252)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:357)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicRootPaneUI$Actions.actionPerformed(BasicRootPaneUI.java:191)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1636)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2851)
    at javax.swing.KeyboardManager.fireBinding(KeyboardManager.java:267)
    at javax.swing.KeyboardManager.fireKeyboardAction(KeyboardManager.java:216)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindingsForAllComponents(JComponent.java:2928)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2920)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2814)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6040)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1848)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:704)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:969)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:841)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:668)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4502)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2475)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:178)
    at java.awt.Dialog$1.run(Dialog.java:1045)
    at java.awt.Dialog$3.run(Dialog.java:1097)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1095)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1563)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1515)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:841)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:985)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.workbench.swing.CreateDialog.showDialog(CreateDialog.java:119)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.workbench.CreateDocumentDialog.createGUI(CreateDocumentDialog.java:307)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.workbench.CreateDocumentDialog.<init>(CreateDocumentDialog.java:84)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.workbench.CreateDocumentDialog.<init>(CreateDocumentDialog.java:79)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.workbench.ClientFrame$9.actionPerformed(ClientFrame.java:253)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
```

How is the format for multi-values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CMIS Workbench cannot create documents with mandatory multi-value properties via the "Create Document" dialog.
But you use the Workbench' console to create such a document.

Comment: Thank you. I have never used the Console til now.